# Can I check pandas dataframe index is end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I use while loop for show data in dataframe

```
while True:
    last_id = get_last_id()
    res = df.iloc[last_id + 1]
```

when last_id end of data and still use last_id + 1 it show error

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Can I check if no last_id + 1 in dataframe index then not show anything ?

Comment: This seems extremely unidiomatic, don’t use loops when working with Pandas unless absolutely necessary. Could you share the rest of your program? I suspect there may be other unidiomatic design choices.

Comment: I want to auto update last value in pandas to database. My pandas index not skip. So I think it better if I check last value in db  if last value in db not equal in pandas then check pandas row and find next row add to db.

Comment: Why are you using a loop? Again, this is unidiomatic and almost never the right solution.

Comment: I'm trying to find new method for solve this problem. I have dataframe like this
0      A-1,
1      A-3,
2      A-4,
3      A-6,
Dataframe will alway increase A-7, A-8 ... and more. I want to run code 1 time only to add last data to database.

Comment: That’s a bit unclear, can you share an example of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if-else` with test by length of `DataFrame`, because selecting by positions:

```
while True:
    last_id = get_last_id()
    if len(df) != last_id + 1:
        res = df.iloc[last_id + 1]
     else:
        print ('cannot select next value after last index')
```

Another idea is use `try-except` statement:

```
while True:
    try:
        last_id = get_last_id()
        res = df.iloc[last_id + 1]
    except IndexError:
        print ('cannot select next value after last index')
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not just remove `+1` from the last line:

```
while True:
    last_id = get_last_id()
    res = df.iloc[last_id]
```

Comment: I know this answer before ask question but this is result.
29    PDF-38,
30    PDF-40,
31    PDF-41,
32    PDF-42,
33    PDF-43,

print(df.iloc[last_idx])
output is
PDF-41
It still show PDF-41 if loop with out +1